# Unable to use binding on Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: android, kotlin, binding

I'm new to mobile coding and I chose Kotlin and Android Studio Giraffe to start this new learning.

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjg_uiSu_-CAxVR_rsIHbjKApkQwqsBegQIDxAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBVAslimaGSk&usg=AOvVaw2ITb7WPsoI6nFpi6e7Bwhm&opi=89978449) tutorial but (at 10 minutes) I get error while adding the binding.

This is my screenShot:

[image]

I googled but I didn't find anything useful to understand what is missing in my project.

I though it should be a missing "Import" but I can't see the import details in the video.

I'll be grateful for any hint.

Edit:

This is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
namespace = "com.example.notessqlite"
compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.notessqlite"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Edit II:

I tried running app (as suggested) but it gave me lots of errors:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Arturo/AndroidStudioProjects/NotesSQLite/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 5; Content is not allowed in prolog.
> at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
> at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:206)
> at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.stripFile(LayoutFileParser.java:469)
> at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutFileParser.parseXml(LayoutFileParser.java:97)
> at android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.processSingleFile(LayoutXmlProcessor.java:161)
> at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$maybeCreateLayoutProcessor$1.processSingleFile(MergeResources.kt:593)
> at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:243)
> at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:299)
> at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:391)
> at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$doFullTaskAction$1$1$2.invoke(MergeResources.kt:268)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
> at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.kt:264)
> at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doTaskAction(MergeResources.kt:320)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:69)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:46)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:45)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.execute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:26)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:93)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:57)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:166)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
> at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:116)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:136)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:121)
> at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:35)
> at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:51)
> at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:54)
> at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:40)
> at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$executeTasks$7(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:172)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$tryTransition$8(StateTransitionController.java:185)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.tryTransition(StateTransitionController.java:185)
> at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.executeTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:172)
> at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.runWork(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:209)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
> at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doRun(DefaultBuildController.java:172)
> at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.access$000(DefaultBuildController.java:47)
> at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.run(DefaultBuildController.java:191)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle files ? Did you sync the project after enabling binding ?

Comment: @ItzDavi I sync the gradle but nothing changed. I added my gradle file to question

Comment: sometimes compiler gives such error, trying building your app once. it will be gone

Comment: @404NotFound I tried running app but it gave me lots of errors:

Comment: Can you please share xml file here?

Comment: @AjayMakwana Do You mean the activity_main.xml?

Comment: @AjayMakwana You were right! The problem was in the activity_main.xml: I found a row at the beginning of the file that didn't have to be there (I was working on two pc at the same time and I think I've used the wrong keybord without noticing ) If you post an answer I'll accept, otherwise I'll delete the question (I think it's useless to other users). Anyway thank you very much

Comment: @genespos Welcome! No need to delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your xml file has some data written before the prolog. There should be nothing before the string, that looks like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and If this didn't work, It is probably an error in you xml file, check it out!